# LXQT task bar: non-repo app icons are missing

Tags: lubuntu, icons, libreoffice, lxqt

Lubuntu 22.04
I have installed non-repository applications, in particular Rstudio, LibreOffice and Discord, and they show up as they are supposed to be in the applications menu, but when I run the apps, their icons are not shown in the task bar which makes navigation difficult. Is there a possible solution? Thanks!